# Javascript: How to change the text inside <p> in a <div> onclick an <a> inside a list

Tags: javascript, html

Onclick anchor tag 'CLICK ON ME' I want to change the text of p tag inside div....

```
<li class="class_1" id="item-1">
  <a href="http://somethingxyz.com/">
  <img src="http://somethingxyz.com/imaqges/image.png" class="mlt-lang">CLICK ON ME</a>
</li>
```

and the p tag in div element where i need to change the text is:-

```
<div class="footer_left">
    <p>This text needs to be change.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: getElementByClass(), onClick() function...but i think i was wrong at coding..can u help me

Comment: @Mukiikumar, it is working for you ?

Comment: #Mihai your code is correct...Thanks

Comment: @Mukiikumar, don't forget to accept answer or vote in order to help other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below Code. And if You Use Link in Anchor tag it will redirect to the link given So you cant See the changes in the current page (though it made the changes)

```
<script> 
function clickchange() {
        var ptag = document.getElementById('par1');
        ptag.innerHTML = 'Observe the Change';
    }
</script>

<li class="class_1" id="item-1">
  <a href="#" onclick="clickchange()">
  <img src="http://somethingxyz.com/imaqges/image.png" class="mlt-lang">CLICK ON ME</a>
</li>
and the p tag in div element where i need to change the text is:-

<div class="footer_left">
    <p id="par1">This text needs to be change.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a jQuery as well.

```js
$(".class_1 > a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".footer_left > p").text("This is New Text"); // Or $(".footer_left > p").html("This is New Text");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li class="class_1" id="item-1">
    <a href="http://somethingxyz.com/">
        <img src="http://somethingxyz.com/imaqges/image.png" class="mlt-lang">CLICK ON ME</a>
</li>


<div class="footer_left">
    <p>This text needs to be change.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to `bind` a click event handler for `a` element. Also, you need to use `event.preventDefault()` in order to prevent the default behavior of the element.

For changing the text you can use `innerHTML` method.

```js
var a=document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
var p=document.querySelector('.footer_left p');
a.onclick=function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   p.innerHTML='changed';
}
```

```html
<li class="class_1" id="item-1">
  <a href="http://somethingxyz.com/">
  <img src="http://somethingxyz.com/imaqges/image.png" class="mlt-lang">CLICK ON ME</a>
</li>
and the p tag in div element where i need to change the text is:-

<div class="footer_left">
    <p>This text needs to be change.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can  do it like this:** use [QuerySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
  <img src="http://somethingxyz.com/imaqges/image.png" class="mlt-lang" onclick="myFunction()">CLICK ON ME</a>


     function myFunction(){

         var p = document.querySelector(".footer_left p");
         p.innerHTML = "your custom content";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ConvertToAnchor ()
{

    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i =0 ; i < paragraphs.length ; i++)
    {
       var textt = paragraphs[i].textContent;

        paragraphs[i].innerHTML = '<a href=http://www.' + textt + '.com>' + textt + '</a>'

    }
}
```

Comment: add some explanation what your code is doing and why you think this will solve the problem